# Mondrian cannot use oracle TNS name as JDBC Data source

Tags: oracle, pentaho, olap, mondrian, tns

Could someone please help with the following issue:

I have 2 JDBC Data sources created in Pentaho BA Server:

1. Oracle Connection with provided user credentials, host, port and SID as database name.
2. Oracle Connections with provided user credentials and TNS name as database name, since if there is SERVICE NAME then I should use TNS name.

Both above connections ping successfully.

When I use the #1 Option as JDBC Data source for my Cube schema - everything works.

But, when I use the #2 Option, cube cannot be loaded and the following exception occurs in the log file:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get connnection 
jdbc:mondrianataSource=Report DB; EnableXmla=false; overwrite=false; 
Locale=en_US; Catalog=mondrian:/My_Cube_Schema; UseContentChecksum=true
at com.pentaho.analyzer.service.impl.OlapConnectionManagerImpl.createConnection(SourceFile:152)
at com.pentaho.analyzer.service.impl.OlapConnectionManagerImpl.createConnection(SourceFile:75)
at com.pentaho.analyzer.service.impl.a.getConnection(SourceFile:55)
```

So, the question is, if it is possible to use the #2 Option, as I have just SERVICE NAME as for connection to DB.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean to say you have created a cube in PSW and you are facing issue at the time of publishing it into BA server?

Comment: @WorkingHard.., No, there is no problem when I publish my cube from PSW. Cube from PSW published successfully. The exception occurs when I try to create Analysis Report. Here are my steps to reproduce: I go to BA Server, Create New -> Analysis Report, and opened Dialog didn't display my cube because of above exception.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind the issue is connection-name.
Connection name should be same in PSW and BA server that is the basic requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however changing Connection Name not helping. Also, in PSW I tried to change connection name to any random name, published it and in BA Server changed JDBC Data source of published cube to one that is already created on BA Server - for one connection it works and for the other it doesn't work. Though both connections successfully pings when I try to edit them in BA Server. The difference between them I wrote in my initial post.

Comment: Have you ever tried with such connection I described as 2nd option in my post? Maybe Mondrian does not support such connection at all?

Comment: After every change I am clearing the cache. Same result.

Comment: ok.No idea then.
let someone who is working with oracle should reply to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, but will not mark it as answer since I was searching the solution that works with TNSName.

From the following page http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC I found 3 valid ways of JDBC URLs:

1. By SID
   `jdbc:oracle:thin:[<user>/<password>]@<host>[:<port>]:<SID>`

Ex.: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl`

2. By Service name
   `jdbc:oracle:thin:[<user>/<password>]@//<host>[:<port>]/<service>`

Ex.: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myhost:1521/orcl`

3. By TNSName
   `jdbc:oracle:thin:[<user>/<password>]@<TNSName>`

Ex.: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=<host>)(PORT=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<service>)))`

Here are my screenshots for my cases described in my question:
For the #1 Option:
*Oracle Connection with provided user credentials, host, port and SID as database name*
[image]

For the #2 Option:
*Oracle Connections with provided user credentials and TNS name as database name, since if there is SERVICE NAME then I should use TNS name.* 
[image]

And finally, the solution that worked for my current situation (Note that Service name is provided with slash):
[image]